# Can't save or import file in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: 22.04, firefox, google-chrome, filesystem, xdg

I can't upload or download files in Firefox or Chrome on my Ubuntu 22.04. Usually when I click on "attach" or "import" buttons, a window appears and I can choose a file on my hard drive.
Now I don't have anything.

In the console I have this for Chrome (when I launch it):

```
[15774:15795:0529/141148.470338:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(623)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: L’interface « org.freedesktop.portal.FileChooser » n’existe pas
```

And in the Firefox console (when I try to import something):

```
firefox:3264): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:52:46.781: Can't open portal file chooser: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: L’interface « org.freedesktop.portal.FileChooser » n’existe pas pour l’objet à l’emplacement /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop
```

I tried a solution telling I should install this:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdg-desktop-portal-gnome xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xdg-desktop-portal-tests xdg-desktop-portal
```

It didn't work...

What am I missing? Everything worked fine until a few weeks ago (first Firefox didn't work, now Chrome).

EDIT: I can't even drag a URL from the address bar to my bookmarks anymore...